# MPI RMA: Order of multiple Lock operations

Tags: locking, mpi, remote-access

I was wondering what was the possible order of execution when locking multiple RMA Windows with MPI. Here's the (python) pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
for win in windows:
    win.Lock(0, LOCK_TYPE)
for win in windows:
    win.Put(something)
for win in windows:
    win.Unlock(0)
print 'Done'
```

My question is: What are the possible order order of execution of these commands ?

The desired behavior is that it first acquires all locks, then puts the `something` into the window, and finally release the locks. However, since MPI locking is non-blocking (it only ensures that the RMA operations will be done when the lock is acquired), is it possible that we `lock`, `put`, and `unlock` the second window all before acquiring the first one ?

Finally, is it possible for the print statement to be executed before the Put operations ? What if it was moved after the `Put(something)` line ?

Thank you very much for your help,
Seba-1511

Comment: Can you more detail about what you need from the code? I don't think this a good pattern. Why do you need so many windows? In any case, MPI-3 might make some of what you are doing simpler.

Comment: Unlock is blocking for all practical purposes. Lock can be a no-op or seem to block in rare cases. Put is always local.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to transmit a couple of matrices from a node to another. I am not sure what your second comment implies: would it be possible for a deadlock to happen or that one set of matrices is partly overridden by another ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a bit more research it would seem that yes, it is possible that we `lock`, `put`, and `unlock` on the second window, before doing it on the first one. As such, it is possible that process 1 `puts` in window 3 and that this put is overwritten by process 2 while process 1 is `putting` in window 2.

What `lock` and `unlock` do is to somehow accumulate all the operations on a RMA window, and if you are using an `EXCLUSIVE_LOCK`, it will perform them atomically on the target. If using a `SHARED_LOCK`, then other operations from other processes can be executed in between. Note that the operations between a `lock` and `unlock` pair are non-blocking, and thus the execution order is not guaranteed.

`print` would always appear last, since as underlined by @Jeff, unlock can be considered blocking.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVzVvg__UK4 at around 1:05:00.